# Pythontex compile with Sublime

Tags: compiling, sublime-text, pythontex

I am trying to use Pythontex with Sublime Text editor.

I have installed the Pythontex package from: https://ctan.org/pkg/pythontex?lang=en

I have then set up Sublime by going to: Preferences > Package Settings > LatexTools > Settings - User

and I have selected the script option for the builder in line 379.

I then have at line 411:

```
        "windows" : {
            "script_commands":
                "pdflatex -shell-escape %.tex|pythontex -shell-escape %.tex|pdflatex -shell-escape %.tex|"
        },
```

My understanding is that this is supposed to compile the pdfLatex, then pythonTex, then again pdfLatex.

I have written the following Latex example here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\title{Sections and Chapters}
\author{Overleaf}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}

This is the first section.

\begin{pycode}
a=2+3
\end{pycode}



\section{Second Section}
This is the second section
My value is $\py{a}$

\end{document}
```

I have saved this in my directory C:\Users\craws\debug
If I go to the cmd terminal, and run the following commands:

```
C:\Users\craws\debug> pdflatex debug.tex
C:\Users\craws\debug> pythontex debug.tex
C:\Users\craws\debug> pdflatex debug.tex
```

This correctly compiles the latex document.
However, if I try using Ctrl + B in Sublime, the build does not update the python code, and so my output becomes:

```
This is the second section My value is 4
```

So using Ctrl+B, I can update the Latex, but not the Python component.
Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following build script solves the problem:

```
"windows" : {
        "script_commands": [
            "pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape ",
            "pythontex",
            "pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape "
        ]
    },
```